# How to get Google GIN working with Google-Eclipse plugin in DevMode?

Tags: java, gwt, dependency-injection, gwt-gin, google-eclipse-plugin

I am experimenting with my first GWT app that uses GIN. I am essentially mimicking the exact same source code example found in their *Getting Started* tutorial. At the end of that tutorial, the author mentions that you need to supply the the GWT compiler with a classpath pointing to the compiled Java binaries. The example they use for doing this [is done using an Ant target](http://code.google.com/p/google-gin/wiki/GinTutorial#Compilation).

Although I will have an automated (Ant-driven) build that also emulates this build task, I want to be able to run/debug my GWT apps from inside of Eclipse without having to kick off an Ant build.

So I ask: when running my GWT app inside Eclipse (Dev Mode), how do I configure the GIN library to point to the compiled classes? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you should need to do is add the `gin.jar` (and dependencies, probably just `guice.jar`) to your project's classpath.

It should *not* be required to copy these to `WEB-INF/lib/`, though depending on your server setup, you may require `guice.jar` there, but never `gin.jar`.